# Github reads previously merged files as new file changes

Tags: git, github

Admittedly I don't understand Git well enough, so I'd really appreciate someone's help here.

Situation:

- We are working off feature branches, branched from test (equivalent to master for this case).
- When we merge PRs we always squash & merge

The Issue:

- PRs detect, in "files changed," files that were JUST merged. In the example below, we merged from dev -> qa, then created a new PR from dev -> qa, and it shows the same files as changed and includes commits that were just merged.

Thanks so much for your help!

First merge:
[image: First merge]

Second PR:
[image: Second PR]

Comment: To be clear, you say that you always use "squash & merge" but your screenshot shows a standard merge-commit at the top. Was that PR merged differently?

Comment: @TonyArra How can you tell the top one is a merge-commit? 

The ones that aren't named "merged PR..." are hotfixes

Comment: @TonyArra I updated the question to be more specific about the fundamental issue. Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: What do the files look like in “changed files”? As if they’re new?

Comment: A squash commit is a new commit id, so qa doesn’t know that it already has those other commits. On your dev branch locally, you can run `git pull origin qa && git push` - this will update dev to match the latest on qa. You can also require that pr’s be up to date with base branches on GitHub, which will provide a button to automatically do this for you.

Comment: I would recommend that if you're going to merge one persistent branch into another persistent branch, you use merge-commits rather than squash-merges. Squash-merging a feature branch into dev makes sense because the feature branch will be deleted afterward. But squashing long-running branches into each other creates confusing git histories, which is what's happening here.

Comment: @JBallin thank you for the replies, I really appreciate you taking the time

- The file changes are the same as those made in the previous merge. For files added in the prev merge, they look as if they're new in "changed files," correct.
- We do get that update button, and that often solves the issue, but not always. Still sees some files as if they're new.

Comment: @TonyArra thank you as well! 

I see what you mean. So is the recommendation to: 
- use squash-merge when merging feature into dev
- use merge-commits when moving dev to qa
?

Comment: @Rav4 ya - by doing that, git will be aware that all of the commits in `dev` - up until the previous merge - are present in `qa`. So on the next `dev -> qa` PR, it knows that you're only interested in merging `dev` changes that have been committed after the previous merge. When you squash, you don't actually merge the histories of your two branches, so `git` assumes that `dev` was never merged into `qa`, even though the file contents may be the same.

Comment: @TonyArra I went through and pushed along the chain with merge commits rather than squash merges, only squash merging from feature to dev. Seeing the same issue. Any other ideas, or information I could provide?

Comment: Can you try reproducing this in a public repo that you can share here?